# Next and Previous Record

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

How can I get `previous` or `next` product_id from table if I have only `varchar` to sort?
Example if I have `PRODUCT_NO='20120033'` and `PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO='yellow'`, I would like to get the next record `PRODUCT_ID which is 4` and I have `PRODUCT_NO='20120033'` and `PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO='green'`, I would like to get the previous record `PRODUCT_ID which is 3`  How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Table structure and data are pasted below

```
CREATE TABLE MYTAB
(
  PRODUCT_ID               NUMBER,
  PRODUCT_NO               VARCHAR2(),
  PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO  VARCHAR2(32)
);


SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into MYTAB
   (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO)
 Values
   (3, '20120033', 'yellow');
Insert into MYTAB
   (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO)
 Values
   (4, '20120033', 'green');
Insert into MYTAB
   (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO)
 Values
   (5, '20120034', 'wine');
Insert into MYTAB
   (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION_NO)
 Values
   (6, '20120034', 'soda');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the lag() and lead() functions:

```
select *
from (
    select product_id,
           product_no,
           product_registration_no, 
           lag(product_id) over (partition by product_no order by product_id) as prev_id,
           lead(product_id) over (partition by product_no order by product_id) as next_id
    from mytab
) 
where product_no='20120033' 
and product_registration_no='green'
```

Note that the concept of "previous" and "next" only makes sense if you can specify a condition to sort on. That's what the `order by product_id` in the window definition does.

Comment: `select product_id,
       product_no,
       product_registration_no, 
       lag(product_id) over (partition by product_no order by product_id) as prev_id
from mytab
where product_no='20120033' and product_registration_no='green'`  this should give `product_id of 3`.